# Do logarithms ever produce rational numbers?

Tags: logarithms

The title is a little nonsensical (so feel free to edit as you see fit)

***Logb(n)*** where ***n*** is a power of ***b*** produces a rational number; for example; ***Log2(8) = 3***

But, ***Log2(3) = 1.5849625007211561814537389439478165087598144076924810604557526545...***

Thus, ***Log2(3)*** produces an irrational number.

Is the same true for any ***Logb(n)*** where ***n*** is not a power of ***b***, or are there cases where this produces a rational number?

Comment: You need to clarify what constraints make this nontrivial. For example, are you asking when $\log_bn$ is a non-integral rational number for integers $b,\,n>2$? If so, hint: writing such a logarithm as $p/q$ with $p,\,q$ co-prime, consider the prime factorizations of each side of $b^p=n^q$ to prove the most general solution is $b=a^q,\,n=a^p$, such as in $\log_48=\frac32$.

Comment: There are some non-integer examples like $\log_2 (2 \sqrt{2} ) = \frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: @J.G. For context, I've been investigating under which circumstances a decimal expansion terminates, repeats periodically, or continues infinitely with no repetition, so I guess my question is, does _Logb(n)_ where _n_ is not a power of _b_ always produces the latter?

Comment: Do you consider $8$ "a power of $4$", or merely consider $4,\,8$ each powers of $2$? (By the way, looking at a few digits of $\log_23$ doesn't prove they never repeat, but my first comment tells you how to verify $\log_23$ is irrational.)

Comment: @J.G. So there is a perfect example of what I was asking. _Log4(8) = 1.5_ and _4^1.5 = 8_, thus, the answer is no, right? (because 1.5 has a terminating decimal expansion)?

Comment: "*but log2(3)=1.584962500...  thus log2(3) produces an irrational number*"  This alone is not sufficient proof.  It may be *evidence* that leads us to *believe* that it may be irrational, but a number beginning with 1.584962500 is not necessarily going to be irrational.  For example 1.584962500 itself is rational.

Comment: For positive integers $b$ and $n$, the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic can be helpful in showing that $\log_b n$ is irrational (when it is in fact irrational). For instance such an argument can be made to show that $\log_2 3$ is irrational.

Comment: With regards to "*Is it true that any $\log_b(n)$ where $n$ is not a rational power of $b$ will be irrational*"  The answer is... of course.  That is precisely what that means.  If $n$ is not a rational power of $b$ then it follows that $n$ is an irrational power of $b$ (*barring nonsensical situations like log base 1 or the logarithm of zero, etc...*).  That is no more interesting than saying "*Is it true that any real number which is not rational is irrational?*"

Comment: If your question was specifically about integers and integer powers, consider $\log_4(8)=1.5$.  Here $8$ is not an integer power of $4$, though it is a rational power of $4$.

Answer (score 0):

The logarithm function is the inverse of the exponential function. So $\log_b x = a \iff x = b^a$.

Thus, if $\log_b x = a$ is rational, then we can write $a = \frac{m}{n}$ where $m$ and $n$ are integers, and so $x = b^\frac{m}{n}$. But by applying power rules we can see that this is equivalent to $x = (b^m)^\frac{1}{n} = \sqrt[n]{b^m}$, i.e. $x$ is the $n$th root of $b^m$.

All of these steps are reversible, meaning that if $x$ is a rational power of $b$, then $\log_b x$ is a rational number and vice versa.